# RadGrid Footer template to add record

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using RadGrid to display assigned customer names to particular salesman. In item template I am binding name of customer with delete button to delete that customer name from that salesman's list. I have a RadComboBox in footer template of Grid. What I want to do is, in needDatasource I am able to bind RadGrid with assigned customer records to that salesman but I also want to display not assigned customers in Combobox of footer template with assign button, When I press assign button, selected customer will be assigned to that sales man and will be displayed in Grid and from combobox that customer will be removed. And on clicking delete button beside the assigned customer name, it will delete the record of customer from grid and will be added to combobox. I don't know which events to be used for this as I am not able to find RadComboBox of footer template in NeedDataSource event. Can anyone help please?

Thank you,
Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve your `RadComboBox`, look in the `GridFooterItem`. To do so, use the `ItemDataBound` Event:

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridFooterItem)
    {
        GridFooterItem item = (GridFooterItem)e.Item;
        RadComboBox yourComboBox = (item.FindControl("yourRadComboBoxID") as RadComboBox);
    }
}
```

Don't forget adding the property to your aspx file:

```
OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound"
```